# Query working on just one parameter Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a query that determines if an alert is inside a bound box, so I pass in top left and bottom right coordinates for comparison.
If I just use alert's `latitude` OR `longitude` `number` field it will then find the records but not when using both. This is strange as if I use 3 other `String` fields `city`, `region` and `country` it does work as expected.
So I tried making `latitude` and `longitude` documents's fields strings but it made no difference.
Can you see why is not working using `latitude` AND `longitude`?
This is the method:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getAlerts(String city, String region, String country,
      double tlLat, double tlLong, double brLat, double brLong) {
    print('Firestore.getAlerts started for bb: tlLat ${tlLat}, tlLong ${tlLong}, brLat ${brLat}, brLong ${brLong}');
    return  _firestore
        .collection('Alert Notifications')
        // .where('country', isEqualTo: country)
        // .where('region', isEqualTo: region)
        // .where('city', isEqualTo: city)

    // not working
    //     .where('latitude', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: tlLat)
    //     .where('longitude', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: tlLong)
    //     .where('latitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: brLat)
    //     .where('longitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: brLong)

    // working with just one parameter either latitude or longitude but not with both
        .where('latitude', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: brLat.toString())
        .where('latitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: tlLat.toString())
        // .where('longitude', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: tlLong.toString())
        // .where('longitude', isLessThanOrEqualTo: brLong.toString())
        .get()
        .catchError((e) {
      log('getAlerts error: $e');
    })
        // .then((value) {
      // print('getAlerts found ${value.docs.length} alerts');
      // return;
    // })
        .whenComplete(() => print('getAlerts completed'));
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know, Firestore queries only accept one each unique parameter. So you can only use `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo` once in your query.

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş well that doesn't really seems to be the problem, If I duplicate the `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo` query params on the same record's field it finds records. It just get scrambled when using it on two different fields..
I see in the FIrestore docs that what I'm trying  to accomplish is not feasible dough. They use GeoPoint type field for this purpose but it only works with a radius.. say for a nearby location find function, but not with bounding box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries can have equality check (`==`) on multiple fields, but can only have range checks (`<=`, `=>`, etc) and inequality checks on a single field. From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

To perform a check on both latitude and longitude of a location, you will need to use a geohash, as shown in this solution page in the documentation on [geoqueries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

Comment: Frenk thank you very much. Indeed GeoPoint and Geohash is the only way to do it in Firestore.

Comment: Correct. If you'd like to learn more about why that is and how they work, have a look at the talk I gave a while ago here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q